# document.getElementById().innerHTML for select tag doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have the following simple script

---

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = '<option>something</option>';"/>    
 <select id="a" style="width: 150px;">
</select>
```

but it doesn't work in IE.
could you tell me why?
thanks

Comment: Related, previous question on cross-browser way to add an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292101/browser-neutral-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-element-in-javascript/292122#292122

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848588/why-does-html-work-and-not-innerhtml-or-appendchild/1849100#1849100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be better off having the AJAX script return a JSON object containing the options you want, then using DOM methods to create the option nodes to match them.

If you really must do this with HTML strings, the way to do it is to write a completely new `<select>` element with the options inside. Then you can copy the information from the `<option>` nodes into to the select you were originally targeting.

```
var select= document.getElementById('a');
select.options.length= 0;

var div= document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML= '<select>'+options+'</select>';
var options= div.firstChild.options;
for (var i= 0; i<options.length; i++) {
    var o= options[i];
    select.options[i]= new Option(o.text, o.value, o.selected);
}
```

Comment: thanks man, i was thinking on it whole day.
i don't know json at all, maybe you can give a link, there i can read about them?

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use jQuery and `html()` instead of `innerHTML`...

So...

```
$("#a").html("<option>Whatever</option>");
```

Works great in all browsers for all objects!

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't tend to like you doing things that way for such items.  Same goes for setting the `innerHTML` of tables.

You should learn to do things the DOM way....for instance, using `createElement ("OPTION")`, then `appendChild()` (first removing children with `removeChild()` if needed).  In general it is way better than `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
optionElement.innerHTML = "some text here";

document.getElementById('a').appendChild(optionElement);
```

Comment: yes, it works, but i use ajax, and in php file i generate ready option list, in that case i can't use appendChild method:(