# Jquery insert values of text-field into list-box.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fetch value from the textfield and add to the listbox.
Here is my `jquery code`

**JS:-**

```
{
$('#btn_AddToList').click(function(
{
    var select = document.getElementById('lst_Regions');
    var region = $('#txt_RegionName').val();

    if('' != region)
    {
        var newOption = document.createElement('option');

        newOption.text = region;
        newOption.value = region;

        if($.browser.msie)
        {
            select.add(newOption);
        }
        else
        {
            select.add(newOption, null);
        }
    }

    return false;
 });
});
```

here is my `html code`

**html:**

```
<input type="text" name="region" id="txt_RegionName" /><br />
<input type="button" name="add" id="btn_AddToList" value="add" class="btn btn-success" /></br />
<select size="10" id="lst_Regions" style="width: 500px;">
</select>
```

**question:** I cannot add the value of the `txt_RegionName` to the `lst_Region` ,where i am going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292101/browser-neutral-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-element-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#btn_AddToList').click(function () {
    var val = $('#txt_RegionName').val();
    $('#lst_Regions').append('<option>' + val + '</option>');
    $('#txt_RegionName').val('').focus();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NJsqg/)**

Comment: Sorry to bother you again , but what if i have more than one text field?? can you please help..

Comment: So if you had a few text inputs and you want to fold them all into the same select? I'm not sure I follow, can you elaborate?

Comment: Currently i have 4 text-field.And i want to display it in the list box as `sr_no`) `Asset_name` 'Particular' `Quantity` at price `cost`.The coatted are the text-field. Can you do the same...

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like:

```
$('#btn_AddToList').click(function(event)
{
    var region = $('#txt_RegionName').val();

    if(region && !$('#lst_Regions>option[value=' + region + ']').length){
        var newOption = $('<option value="' + region + '">' + region + '</option>');

        $('#lst_Regions').append(newOption);
    }

    //return false;
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

just to let you know, you can prevent it from duplicate values using:

```
$('#lst_Regions>option[value=' + region + ']').length
```

which has to be zero, and as you see I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    {
        $('#btn_AddToList').click(function()
        {
            var select = document.getElementById('lst_Regions');
            var region = $('#txt_RegionName').val();

            if ('' != region) {
                $(document.createElement('option')).text(region).val(region).appendTo(select);
            }
            return false;
        });
    };
```